# How to set the value of a secret in GCP through CLI?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

I have script written in bash where I create a key with a certain name.

```
#!/bin/bash

project_id="y"
secret_id="x"
secret_value="test"
gcloud config set project "$project_id"
gcloud secrets create "$secret_id" --replication-policy="automatic"
```

I want to be able to also directly add the secret-value to my secret, so that I do not have to go into my GCP account and set it manually (which would defeat the purpose). I have seen that it is possible to attach files through the following command, however there does not seem to be a similar command for a secret value.

```
--data-file="/path/to/file.txt"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/secrets/create#--data-file:

> --data-file=PATH
> File path from which to read secret data. Set this to "-" to read the secret data from stdin.

So set `--data-file` to `-` and pass the value over stdin. Note, if you use `echo` use `-n` to avoid adding a newline.

```
echo -n $secret_value | gcloud secrets create ... --data-file=-
```